# APEX display value after upgrade to 4.2.2

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

After upgrade Oracle APEX from  4.1.0.00.32 to 4.2.2.00.11 I have problem with display value on a Page in item Display As = TextArea.
Value stored in Database field is 'šđčćžŠĐČĆŽ'. In APEX version 4.1 this field on Page displayed like stored in database field.
In APEX version 4.2 this field on Page displayed with value '&#x0161;&#x0111;&#x010D;&#x0107;&#x017E;&#x0160;&#x0110;&#x010C;&#x0106;&#x017D;'.
Oracle database version is 11gR2.

Is anybody have same or similar situation?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have Application Express 4.2.2.00.11, and I tried to reproduce your issue but I haven't been able to. I inserted the value you mention on the database and created a TextArea to display it, and it looks fine:

[image: text displayed correctly]

I would probably try the following:

- Make sure is not the browser
- Play with the globalization settings under *Shared components -> Globalization*
- Try with different types of fields